# Dracula theme not changing everything to dracula type dark mode

Tags: themes

I recently installed Dracula theme from its official website, but I found that the Dracula theme is not working for all of the window panes and applications. For example

1. the Chrome internal pages are still in white mode.

   [image]
2. The panel which shows calendar and notifications along with extensions menu also turned to white.

   [image]

   [image]
3. The search window has also become white.

   [image]

Is there any way to fix this issue? Is this a bug or I have not disabled something?

Comment: Not a bug and doubt it is something you disabled. Changing the theme does not affect Snap apps.

Comment: but when i had the normal dark theme the ubuntu has in its settings > apprearence > dark that would make my chrome pages load in dark mode i installed the dracula theme and the chrome started loading pages in light mode

Comment: An issue with that theme then. I would contact the maker of the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Open Extension Manager, Go in brose tab and search for user themes and make sure its installed
[The first extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EyqR.png)
Then return back to the Installed section and scoll down to find the User Themes Extension and make sure its enabled
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efV7c.png)
Then open the Gnome Tweaks tool, If you dont know how to download and install gnome tweaks tool heres a [guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-use-gnome-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu/) ,in Gnome Tweaks tool go in Appearence window and in Shell Select the Appropriate theme in This case GTK-master
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb2zM.png)
If the theme for Shell is disabled try restarting and that may fix the issue

Comment: Rather then having links in the answer and sending the OP off to look at other sites the necessary info belongs in your answer. This answer as written is incomplete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @David it says you are not able to embed images as your reputation is below 10 instead of that links are added